# How to upgrade my electron version from 6 to 9 to avoid errors

Tags: javascript, sqlite, electron

I would like to upgrade my electron version from 6 a stable version to 9 because of a
problem with my api I have tryied npm fund and npm audit but it doesn't correct the
problem may be someone have an other way to do that these are the errors I'm getting :

(electron) The default value of app.allowRendererProcessReuse is deprecated, it is
currently "false".  It will change to be "true" in Electron 9.  For more information
please check https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397
node-pre-gyp info This Node instance does not support builds for Node-API version 6
node-pre-gyp info This Node instance does not support builds for Node-API version 6
node-pre-gyp info This Node instance does not support builds for Node-API version 6
node-pre-gyp info This Node instance does not support builds for Node-API version 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `package.json` file (which should be at the root directory of your project), edit your devDependencies Electron version line to `"electron": "^9.0.0"` and save the file.

Next, open a command line at the root of your project and run `npm install`.

See [Manually editing the `package.json` file](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file#manually-editing-the-packagejson-file) for more information.

Comment: it works but I have a problem with the api I'm getting this error: node-pre-gyp info This Node instance does not support builds for Node-API version 6

Comment: What OS are you using? Additionally, what version of node are you using? Type `node -v` at the command prompt to find out. PS: If you are using Windows and nvm to manage your node instances, type `nvm list` at the command prompt as well and comment on your results.

Comment: I am using sqllite as database  and my node version is v16.14.2 and  I am using vue.js as api to reach sqlite

Comment: I'm using windows as os  and npm to manage my node instances